# NHibernate 3.0 Linq Provider. Select not working after Skip and Top

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Hi I use NHiberante to fill my web app's paged and ordered grid.
It was working just fine until i decided to put projection in action.

This is the original, working code:

```
var data = repository
    .Where(predicate);
    .OrderBy(columns)
    .Skip(amount)
    .Take(anotherAmount);
```

Then I've started introducing my projection and it worked fine too:

```
var data = repository
        .Where(predicate);
        .OrderBy(columns)
        .Select(myProjection);
```

I was happy that everything works so I added missing Skip and Take, but stop - now Nhibernate states that Select is not supported (NotSupportedException). Code:

```
var data = repository
        .Where(predicate);
        .OrderBy(columns)
        .Skip(amount)
        .Take(anotherAmount)
        .Select(projection);
```

It's a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is a known bug. 
http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-2317

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this was a bug in NH. In 3.3.1.4000 version it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you call .Count() you're executing the query, the query no longer exists. You need to issue two seperate queries to get the Count and List.

You can do something fancy with Future<> or MultiQuery.

Edit:
http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/16c296414aedc09d

The second post on here should be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Count() is not the case here (the error remains if I remove it), so I will remove it from code samples.

Comment: Oh, can you show the entire query, the part from the repository too?

Comment: repository is just LinqProvider - taken from ISession.Query<Entity>

Comment: 99% sure the Linq provider doesn't support projections, you would need to use QueryOver.

Comment: it does (I wrote it - second code sample works fine), but thanks for your time :)

Comment: I just fired up a project and checked Query, get no option for projections on Select. But on QueryOver I do get the option for projections on Select... Not sure how you got it to work :( Sorry.